# PHP Vs JQuery Web api2

Tags: php, security, web, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

Well, the title is really bad here, but I had no other way to explain what is happing my server.

I have a normal web api2, new. I installed cross domain and only putted

`config.EnableCors()`; on `webapiconfig`.

I have a MailController Which contains this method :

```
 [HttpPost]//omUrl/{url?}
        [Route(@"~/api/Mail/MailOpen")]
        public void MailOpen()
        {
            try
            {
                File.Create(@"D:\Emails\Alive.html");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }
```

and run on a web with this host: `http://localhost:56212/`

So, i am trying to post some data to check cross domain policy and i post with this php code :

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://localhost:56212/api/Mail/MailOpen';
$data = array('Smtp' => 'value1', 'Subject' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
 ?>
```

This code gets to the server and the Alive.html is created, Wait. How can that be i asked my self, i don't have any cross domain policy yet on this controller ?..

So i tryed to run this javascript code :

```
<script>

 $.get(
     "http://localhost:56212/api/Mail/MailOpen",
     { 'G': "aa94a7cf-7794-41ff-b8d0-fcfe34fcb19c" }, // put your parameters here
     function (responseText) {
           console.log(responseText);

     }

    );
</script>
```

Which suppose to do the same thing.. but I get this error :

> jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:56212/api/Mail/MailOpen?G=aa94a7cf-7794-41ff-b8d0-fcfe34fcb19c m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4m.each.m.(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4m.extend.getJSON @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ index.html:6
>       index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:56212/api/Mail/MailOpen?G=aa94a7cf-7794-41ff-b8d0-fcfe34fcb19c. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Which is normal, because I don't have any policy yet.

Can any one tell me why the php worked and the jQuery return an error?

Ty all.]

Edit :

Well this is even more bad.. I just saw I am trying to use `GET` to post.

So I change my request to post, and the server took it and it worked, it even created the file, but give  me an error `index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:56212/api/Mail/MailOpen. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

How can it give an error and still work?

Better yet, how is this even working!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is a security mechanism that is browser-specific. Your PHP is not a typical web browser, and does not require CORS policies be enforced.

From Wikipedia:

> The CORS standard describes new HTTP headers which provide browsers and servers a way to request remote URLs only when they have permission. Although some validation and authorization can be performed by the server, it is generally the browser's responsibility to support these headers and respect the restrictions they impose.
>   For AJAX and HTTP request methods that can modify data (usually HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request header, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method. Servers can also notify clients whether "credentials" (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should be sent with requests.